# Parsing a json file using just javascript not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

UPDATE - I have the following page.  It's working in Chrome and Firefox, but I also need it to work in IE 11.  I can not use jQuery - just plain javascript.  Can anyone provide any help?  I have changed the api url to a fake one.  I'd really appreciate any help - not the greatest at Javascript.  It does seem to choke on the following line: `res.results.map(f => {`   I do not know what to change this line to make it work.  Like I said - not much experience with javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="profile">
                <table id= "userdata" border="2">
                <thead>
                    <th>Organization</th>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                    <th>Account Created</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
                var table = document.getElementById("userdata");
                var people = [];
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                        console.log(res.results);
                        res.results.map(f => {
                            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.account + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + f.service_key + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + f.service_url + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.created_at + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.id + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                            table.innerHTML += tblRow;
                        });
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", true);
                xhttp.send(); 
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE - I replaced that line with function(f) and now its saying unexpected token:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div class="profile">
            <table id= "userdata" border="2">
               <thead>
                  <th>Organization</th>
                  <th>Service</th>
                  <th>URL</th>
                  <th>Account Created</th>
                  <th>ID</th>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
            <script>
         (function() {

         var table = document.getElementById("userdata"); 

         var people = [];
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              var res = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
              console.log(res.results);
               function(f) {
              var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.account + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + f.service_key + "</td>" + 
                                    "<td>" + f.service_url + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.created_at + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.id + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                                    table.innerHTML += tblRow;
              }); 
             }
           };
           xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", true);
           xhttp.send(); 
                    })();
         </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get in IE? In older versions the use of `console` broke the script - did you try without `console.log` in IE?

Comment: It seems like it's choking on the following line:   res.results.map(f=>{

Comment: This has nothing to do with parsing JSON. You're using an arrow function. Arrow functions are not supported in IE11.